# Why does this Access database query result in a syntax error?

Tags: c#

I am using an Access database For my WinForms application, written in C#. I am trying to fetch only those rows with a specified value. What is the correct syntax? I tried this query but am getting syntax error for this part of query:

```
WHERE Type_of_Dr='Referral' and Display='true'
```

The full query:

```
SELECT DoctorID,FirstName,LastName From Doctor_Master Order By LastName WHERE Type_of_Dr='Referral' and Display='true'
```

Comment: try move the order by after the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Where using after order by(As pointed out by SenthilKumar) and `Display='true'` As `Display` Column seems to store Boolean Values value should not have single quotes, hence write like this `Display=true`

It should be like this

```
SELECT DoctorID,FirstName,LastName From Doctor_Master WHERE Type_of_Dr='Referral' and Display=true Order By LastName
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DoctorID,FirstName,LastName From Doctor_Master Order By LastName WHERE Type_of_Dr='Referral' and Display='true'
```

Problem is Where using after order by

```
SELECT DoctorID,FirstName,LastName From Doctor_Master WHERE Type_of_Dr='Referral' and Display='true' Order By LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

As SenthilKumar pointed out, the `ORDER BY` clause must come after the `WHERE` clause. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp; I encourage you to work through the aforementioned tutorial: it's very easy.